# Probability that the number of red balls removed from the bag is 4

Tags: probability

A bag contains 15 balls of the same shape and size. Of these, 9 balls are blue, and the remaining 6 balls are red. Suppose 7 balls are removed randomly (without replacement) from the bag, in such a way that any 7 balls originally in the bag is equally likely to be the 7 balls that are removed from the bag. What is the probability that the number of red balls removed from the bag is exactly 4?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Comment: @Moravitz please check if my answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $15\choose 7$ ways to make the required selections.  Of these, there are ${9\choose 3}\cdot {6\choose 4}$ ways to choose exactly $4$ red balls.

Therefore your solution should be 
$$\frac{{9\choose 3}\cdot{6\choose 4}}{15\choose 7}$$

Comment: Thanks @Man pleasure to help you